# issue about reading excel file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, excel

I try to read an excel file in Asp.Net. I have this errror:

```
Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\tablobilgisayar.xlsx'. There are several possible reasons:
• The file name or path does not exist.

• The file is being used by another program.

• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.
```

My codes are:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelObj = null;
        ExcelObj = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook theWorkbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(
           @"C:\tablobilgisayar.xlsx", 0, true, 5,
           "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false,
            0, true);
```

I have this file on my disk, and path is true. I also use IIS 7.5. I think that it is about IIS. Because I copy paste files to another empty asp.net project that uses Visual Studio's local IIS, and it worked.

Is someone give an idea about this? Thanks.

Comment: You should be aware that Microsoft does not support or recommend Interop from ASP.NET. [MS Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Answer (score 0):

make sure IIS has permission on that location.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, you CAN read the files via Interop from Excel, but it is not recommended because it is slow, excel has to be installed on the server and may cause your thread to hang.
A good alternative is the library to read *xlsx / *.xlsm files is EPPLUS, which is free, much better to use (use linq, datatable etc. directly without the cumbersome interop interface) and 1000% faster (I am not kidding).
I know, you have to change your app and that sucks, but I tried Interop before and was shocked hoch much better the alternatives are.